# Perl: Pass open file handle to a program reading STDIN

Tags: perl, redirect, fork, filehandle

I read a few lines from STDIN. How can I pass the remaining of STDIN to a command that reads from standard input (e.g. `md5sum` or `wc`)?

I could do a:

```
read_a_few_lines_from_diamond_operator();
open (C, "|cmd");
while(<>) { print C }
close C;
cleanup_after_C();
```

but for efficency reasons I would like not to touch the input, but instead pass the filehandle of STDIN. Sort of like:

```
seq 10 | (read A; wc)
```

where `read` reads as much as it likes before passing the rest on to `wc`. I cannot use this solution, though, as I need to start the command from inside my perl program and I need to do work after `cmd` completes.

---

I read a few lines from the file 'foo'. How can I pass the remaining to a command that reads from standard input (e.g. `md5sum` or `wc`)?

I could do a:

```
open (F, "<foo");
read_a_few_lines_from_F();
open (C, "|cmd");
while(<F>) { print C }
close C;
cleanup_after_C();
```

but for efficency reasons I would like not to touch the input, but instead pass the rest of file 'foo'.

---

I have a feeling it can to be done using trickery like `select`, `open(FOO,">&STDOUT)`, `exec 6<&0`, `fork`, `pipe`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: You don't need to do anything special. Your child will automatically  inherit your `STDIN` with `system` and `exec`. Everything you haven't read from STDIN will be readable by the child.

There is a problem, though. Because reading one character at a time would be crazy inefficient, Perl reads from the file a block at a time. That is to say you read more from the file than the "few lines" you got back from Perl. This can clearly be seen using the following command:

```
perl -E'say $_ x 500 for "a".."z"' \
   | perl -e'<>; <>; exec("cat");' \
   | less
```

Instead of starting at the start of the second line, `cat` starts in the middle of the "q"s (at byte 8192)!

You'd have to switch from reading lines with `readline` (`<>`) to reading individual bytes with `sysread` if you wanted this to work.

---

Focusing on the bigger picture, I think there is a solution:

```
open(STDIN, "<", "foo") or die $!;
read_a_few_lines(*STDIN);
my $pos = tell(STDIN);
open(STDIN, "<", "foo") or die $!;
sysseek(STDIN, $pos, SEEK_SET);
system(@cmd);
...
```

Or maybe even:

```
open(STDIN, "<", "foo") or die $!;
read_a_few_lines(*STDIN);
sysseek(STDIN, tell(STDIN), SEEK_SET);
system(@cmd);
...
```

Untested.

Comment: Elegant solution which earns you a thumbs up, but it has 2 problems: It kills off perl (I have clarified the question to make it clear that this will not work for me); and it does not deal with the 2nd part (reading the file 'foo').

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Like the answer says, it works for `system` as well as `exec`.  Does `perl -e 'print <>; system("cat"); print "still here\n"' <file` not represent the bare-bones case of your scenario?

Comment: Well spotted. This works: `seq 10 | perl -e 'sysread(STDIN,$a,1); print "$a bar";system("cat"); print "still here\n"'`. It still leaves reading the file 'foo', though.

Comment: @Ole Tange, Missed that bit since I didn't think you'd want the silly solution of using `sysread`. Just use `open(STDIN, '<', 'foo') or die $!;` Or if you don't want to clobber the parent's STDIN, `open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', 'foo') or die $!; waitpid(open3('<&CHILD_STDIN', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR', @cmd), 0);`